# Logging syntax details

Tags: java, logging, syntax

I have a simple question on logging
why it is common to use this syntax for logging:

```
LOG.debug("invalidate {}",_clusterId);
```

not this:

```
LOG.debug("invalidate" + _clusterId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, say you have the logging level set to INFO. You'd like to ignore debug-level messages entirely. But the log method can't check the log level until the method is entered, after it gets the parameters. So if you don't know if you're going to need a parameter it's better to avoid having to evaluate it.

With your second example, even though logging is set to info, _clusterId gets toString called on it, then that resulting string is concatenated with the preceding string. Then once the method is entered the logger figures out the debug level doesn't need logging and it throws away the newly-created string and exits the method.

With the first example if debug-level logging is not enabled then _clusterId doesn't get toString called on it and the log message doesn't get built. Calling toString may be slow or create garbage, it's better to avoid it for cases where nothing is going to be logged anyway.

Here's the source code for the debug method on log4j's org.apache.log4j.Category (which is the superclass of Logger):

```
public void debug(Object message, Throwable t) {
  if(repository.isDisabled(Level.DEBUG_INT))
    return;

  if(Level.DEBUG.isGreaterOrEqual(this.getEffectiveLevel()))
    forcedLog(FQCN, Level.DEBUG, message, t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a statement with several parameters, writing the pattern as a string followed by the parameters makes the code more readable. It may also be more efficient, avoiding the needless creation of many temporary string objects, but that depends on how the logging framework implements interpolation internally.

To see the first point, compare this with the equivalent line that uses string concatenation.

```
LOG.debug("{}: Error {} while processing {} at stage {}", currentFile, 
        exception.getMessage(), operation.getName(), operation.getStage())
```

When there's only one parameter it doesn't really matter which one you use, apart from being consistent with the general case.